# Spark dataframe insert values if doesn't exist

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have dataframe like this:

[image]

but sometimes some rows are missing I need to dermine what rows are missing and then insert such row.All the values are known
What is best way to do it in Spark(prefer in python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding properly, the "missing" values will be indicates by a skipped `foo`. In this case, what you're looking for is an outer join.

Suppose you have two data frames. Your original one, call it `df`:

```
+---+-----+
|foo|value|
+---+-----+
|  a|    1|
|  b|    2|
+---+-----+
```

And the one with your known values, call it `defaults`:

```
+---+------+
|foo|value2|
+---+------+
|  c|     3|
|  b|     3|
+---+------+
```

An outer join gives you the following:

```
>>> jd = df.join(defaults, on="foo", how='outer')
>>> jd.show()
+---+-----+------+
|foo|value|value2|
+---+-----+------+
|  c| null|     3|
|  b|    2|     3|
|  a|    1|  null|
+---+-----+------+
```

We now just have to combine the two value columns, taking `value` first if it's defined:

```
>>> jd = jd.withColumn("result", coalesce("value", "value2"))
>>> jd.show()
+---+-----+------+------+
|foo|value|value2|result|
+---+-----+------+------+
|  c| null|     3|     3|
|  b|    2|     3|     2|
|  a|    1|  null|     1|
+---+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: But I need that if value if present that it will not be exchanged with default value

Comment: That's handled by the `coalesce`--it takes the first non-null value it encounters.

Comment: What if I don't need the value1 and the value2 columns I need stay only with result  and foo column