# How to do Upsert in Pyspark from one layer to another layer in HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Below is the data in raw layer. What I need is when new data comes in and if the registrationid already exists then I need to overwrite that row. If the registrationid does not exist, I need to insert that data.   How to do it in Pyspark? Can anyone help?

Raw_layer:

```
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|registrationid|dischargedate|deathdate|status_description|dischargetype|dischargesubtype|stage|remarks|
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|    1000003657|   27/04/2023|     null|    Not Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003658|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003659|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003660|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
```

New record comes in

```
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|registrationid|dischargedate|deathdate|status_description|dischargetype|dischargesubtype|stage|remarks|
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|    1000003657|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003661|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
```

Need the output like this in the Curated_layer:

```
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|registrationid|dischargedate|deathdate|status_description|dischargetype|dischargesubtype|stage|remarks|
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|    1000003657|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003658|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003659|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003660|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003661|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
```

Comment: try using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49464195/3438069

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so.
Assuming `raw_df` is the Raw_layer dataframe and `new_df` is the New records dataframe :

```
raw_df.show()
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|registrationid|dischargedate|deathdate|status_description|dischargetype|dischargesubtype|stage|remarks|
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|    1000003657|   27/04/2023|     null|    Not Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003658|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003659|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003660|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
```

```
new_df.show()
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|registrationid|dischargedate|deathdate|status_description|dischargetype|dischargesubtype|stage|remarks|
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|    1000003657|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003661|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
```

---

### Solution with coalesce

Vikas offered the solution from [Spark dataframe insert values if doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49463708/spark-dataframe-insert-values-if-doesnt-exist/49464195#49464195) with coalesce, so I'm gonna add something different. Try and select the one you prefer.

---

### Solution with union and left_anti joins

```py
curated_df = new_df.unionAll(
    raw_df.join(new_df, on="registrationid", how="left_anti")
)

curated_df.show()
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|registrationid|dischargedate|deathdate|status_description|dischargetype|dischargesubtype|stage|remarks|
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|    1000003657|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003661|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003658|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003659|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003660|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
```

---

### Solution with window functions

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

curated_df = new_df.withColumn("rnk", F.lit(1)).union(
    raw_df.withColumn("rnk", F.lit(2))
)

curated_df = (
    curated_df.withColumn(
        "rnk", F.row_number().over(W.partitionBy("registrationid").orderBy("rnk"))
    )
    .where("rnk=1")
    .drop("rnk")
)

curated_df.show()
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|registrationid|dischargedate|deathdate|status_description|dischargetype|dischargesubtype|stage|remarks|
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|    1000003657|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003658|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003659|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003660|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003661|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: curated_df = new_df.unionAll(
    raw_df.join(new_df, on="registrationid", how="left_anti")
) .. When I use this, I am getting duplicate records. if the registrationid are same then I need to overwrite with the latest registrationid.

Comment: That's weird. left_anti should only keep the registrationid which are not in new_df. Or it means you have duplicates in new_df.

Comment: Lets say I have a registrationid as 1000003657 and status_description as "Not Discharged" in curated layer. If this registrationid 1000003657 comes again in the new_data with status_description as Discharged. I need to overwrite the data or the status_description should be changed to Discharged. If I get a new registrationid, then I should insert it. Any solution for it?

Comment: @RajakumarS I'm sorry but I do not really get your point. I tried your data with my code and the output matches. With your current use case, it works. Therefore, you should probably add more details in your question with missing or failing use case.